# Waiting for/receiving an external web service request in cucumberjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, callback, cucumberjs

I think I just need a pointer in the right direction.

I am testing an application server (through its REST API). I'm using cucumberjs

When I invoke a specific method, some time later the application will send a notification to a URL. The URL is configurable, but only in the app settings - i.e. I can't give a callback URL for each invocation.

In my test step, I need to wait for (and receive) that notification, and extract some data from the request body to use in later steps.

How do I go about this? I guess I could set up a web server for each scenario, pass it a reference to my World object, and have it update something there with the details of the notification (it's OK to configure the app settings to point at my testing app).

But how do I wait (with a timeout) for the notification to be received?

(Ideas, and pointers to doc I should have found, suggestions for node.js packages  etc. all welcomed)

Answer (score 0):

I am performing similar types of testing where I need to trigger something in a could-based system and then wait for some behavior to occur. In order to achieve this, I'm using the [promise-retry NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-retry) to perform polling (when needed) and then configuring the default timeouts in CucumberJS to be higher than normal (usually around 60 seconds). I also use [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) to make all these timing configurations easier to manage.

As far as how you're interacting with your system, it depends on what type of system it is. If you're using Azure, AWS, or Firebase there are API clients that they provide.

If you need to poll, I would recommend a promise-based HTTP client like [flashheart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flashheart), [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), or [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent). CucumberJS itself does not provide these capabilities, but it's easy to bring in other modules for CucumberJS to integrate with.

If you want to receive notifications directly, you could use some sort of cloud-based event hub like [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/). Alternatively, if your tests are running on the same network as the system you could easily run an [Express HTTP server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) within CucumberJS. As you receive messages, push them onto an array and then have a step definition to assert that the array contains the expected message.

Comment: "I would recommend a promise-based HTTP client".  I'm not really working on this any more, but i needed a server, not a client. A notification was sent to me, Hence polling, http clients don't really work for me.